# Prove $\left(\frac{a+b}{c} + \frac{b+c}{a} + \frac{c+a}{b}\right)\left(\frac{ab}{c^2+b^2} + \frac{bc}{a^2 + c^2} + \frac{ca}{a^2 + b^2}\right) \ge 9$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, arithmetic

If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}$,then prove that the following inequality holds:

$$\left(\frac{a+b}{c} + \frac{b+c}{a} + \frac{c+a}{b}\right)\left(\frac{ab}{c^2+b^2} + \frac{bc}{a^2 + c^2} + \frac{ca}{a^2 + b^2}\right) \ge 9 \tag{1}$$

---

This is a inequality posted on the [AoPS site](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=560731) and it's been answered by one user. The problem is that I can't quite understand the proof. The proof is:

After using AM-GM we need to prove:

$$(a^2c + a^2b + b^2c + b^2a + c^2a + c^2b)^3 \ge 27abc(a^2+b^2)(a^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2) \tag{2}$$

which holds from AM-GM.

The second part is clear to me, but I can't understand the part when he transforms $(1)$ into $(2)$. Because he said he used AM-GM I apply that inequality on both terms in $(1)$, but i end up with:

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)a^2b^2c^2}{abc(a^2+b^2)(a^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2)}} \ge 1$$

And I don't know how to continue. I used the fact that:$$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) = a^2c + a^2b + b^2c + b^2a + c^2a + c^2b + 2abc$$

But the term $a^2b^2c^2$ in the numerator is making troubles.

From AM-GM  and Nesbitt's Inequality we know that the first term on the LHS in $(1)$ is $\ge 6$ and i tried proving

$$\frac{ab}{c^2+b^2} + \frac{bc}{a^2 + c^2} + \frac{ca}{a^2 + b^2} \ge \frac 32$$

But again I end up with empty hands.

How can I prove it? Can someone explain me the first part in the AoPS answer?

Comment: $$\left(\frac{a+b}{c} + \frac{b+c}{a} + \frac{c+a}{b}\right) = \frac{a^2c + a^2b + b^2c + b^2a + c^2a + c^2b}{abc},$$
$$\left(\frac{ab}{c^2+b^2} + \frac{bc}{a^2 + c^2} + \frac{ca}{a^2 + b^2}\right) \ge 3 \frac{\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}}{\sqrt[3]{(a^2+b^2)(a^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2)}}.$$

Comment: Thank you @njguliyev. You can make it an answer, so I can accept it. Anyway I had an intuition that we need to apply AM-GM on just one term, because if we work backwards, we'll get 3 on the RHS. But bringing the first term under common GCD was the key to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As njguliyev pointed out,

$$\left(\frac{a+b}{c} + \frac{b+c}{a} + \frac{c+a}{b}\right) = \frac{a^2c + a^2b + b^2c + b^2a + c^2a + c^2b}{abc}$$

$$\left(\frac{ab}{c^2+b^2} + \frac{bc}{a^2 + c^2} + \frac{ca}{a^2 + b^2}\right) \ge 3 \frac{\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}}{\sqrt[3]{(a^2+b^2)(a^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2)}}$$

Comment: Yes, and AM-GM again.